# How can I filter an array to update tableview?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, filter

Hello I'm really new to Swift, I have a problem after filter the array I can't update it into my tableview

I tried to use `filter()` but I don't know how can I update the `tableview.reloadData()` doesn't work.

These code are written in button's IBAction method. I want to like when tap on button it will update the tableview with filter but getting warning as below

> Result of call to 'filter' is unused

```
   @IBAction func oneTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    if staroneBtn.isSelected == true{

        staroneBtn.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "1stared"), for: .normal)
        hotelArray.filter(){$0.star == 1}
        self.tbView.reloadData()

    } else if staroneBtn.isSelected == false{
        staroneBtn.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "1star"), for: .normal)
    }
    staroneBtn.isSelected = !staroneBtn.isSelected
}

@IBAction func twoTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if startwoBtn.isSelected == true{
        startwoBtn.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "2stared"), for: .normal)
        hotelArray.filter(){$0.star == 2}
        self.tbView.reloadData()
}else if startwoBtn.isSelected == false{
        startwoBtn.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "2star"), for: .normal)
    }
    startwoBtn.isSelected = !startwoBtn.isSelected

}
```

So far as I do a research I found that I need to change CellforRows function but I have no idea how to do it.

Please help.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as? HotelTableViewCell else{return UITableViewCell()}

    cell.NameLbl.text = hotelArray[indexPath.row].hotelName

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning itself says that you need to user the result of filter like below...

```
 hotelArray = hotelArray.filter {$0.star == 1}
```

You need to make `hotelArray` as `var`.

Comment: i feel so dumb haha.I really appreciate it .Thank you.

Comment: @FroZi24,@Mahendra  you don't need to use function after the filter.

Answer (score 1):

The `filter` is higher order function in swift, you can use it to filter out an array. Below is the code you can use to resolve the issue.

```
    hotelArray = hotelArray.filter { (obj) -> Bool in
        return obj.star == 1
    }
```

or

```
hotelArray = hotelArray.filter { $0.star == 1 }
```

Comment: @FroZi24 Great!!1

Answer (score 0):

Using only one array won't work like (`hotelArray = hotelArray.filter {$0.star == 1}`)

You need to maintain 2 arrays of data other wise only first time filtered data will be correct not afterwards.
Take one unFilteredHotelsData array, and second filteredHotelsData array for tableview's data source.

Then you need to getFilteredData every time rating filter is changed like

```
filteredHotelsData = unFilteredHotelsData.filter { $0.star == 1 }
tableView.reloadData()
```

and in delegate method `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)` return `filteredHotelsData.count`